# a generic error occurred gdi+ c#

Tags: c#, image, save, devexpress, gdi+

i would like to save image with the same name and path after a rotation.
i've got an error in the methode save (**a generic error occurred gdi+**)

Here's the code :

```
string path = @"mypath";
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(path + aspximage.ImageUrl, true);
image.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
//The error is generated here
image.Save(path + aspximage.ImageUrl, ImageFormat.Png);
// I have added this line so that the browser can display it
aspximage.ImageUrl = aspximage.ImageUrl + "&t=" + DateTime.Now.Second;
```

i get my image from a local path in hard drive. for that i use an **ashx handler** so my imageUrl is something like **"Handler.ashx?n=nameimage.png"**

Here's the code of Handler.ashx :

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    string imgName = context.Request.QueryString["n"];
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    string path = @"myPath" + imgName;
    Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
    image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

If i remove this line

```
// I have added this line so that the browser can display it
aspximage.ImageUrl = aspximage.ImageUrl + "&t=" + DateTime.Now.Second;
```

My code turns well but the browser is not able to reload my image.

and if i leave it my code works well, but the error is generated after **3 or more execution calls** on the same image.

what are your suggestions ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which version of DevExpress are you using?? It may be possible that this issue does not repro on our side. could you provide a small sample app to repro the behaviour?. It will easy to identify that issue is in your application or in controls.  DevExpress support is the best place to ask a question which look like control error rather than application error..

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply, 

the problem is not in DevExpress control, even if i changed by another control asp i still have the same error.

The error is generated only when i add **DateTime.Now.Second** in my Image URL and only after 3 or more execution calls on the same image.
If i remove the **DateTime.Now.Second**   browser can not anymore able to reload my image cause the url image has not changed.

Could you tell me please about another solution to rotate image 90° and save it in my path and reload it again either in JS (Client side) or (Server side) ?

Comment: Make a ajax call which return image in format of base64 string after doing rotation operation on your saved image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the error.

I should close the file once i have saved the image in context.Response.outputStream "**Handler.ashx**"

for that i added **image.Dispose()**

Here's the new code of Handler.ashx :

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    string imgName = context.Request.QueryString["n"];
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    string path = @"mypath" + imgName;
    Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
    image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    //I added this line
    image.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: A better practice is to wrap the entire image handling in a `using` block.